# How do i create a form text input with examples below?

Tags: forms, textinput

For so long, I've been wondering how to create a text input in a form, with examples dropping down below. This explanation might sound weird, so I've got an [example](http://www.flysas.com/en/us/), where you insert a word, or in other cases an airport code, and you can click what you mean below.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this website: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

It has pretty good basic html lessons and will help you get your desired result.

Comment: I actually had this site open in another tab when i wrote this. From my guessing, the kind of text field i am looking for is based on either javascript or CSS

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood.  You're talking more along the lines of a dynamic dropdown from the contents of a textbox.  I'd start with something like this: http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/javascript/dynamicCombo.html

then modify it to use a textbox and a listbox.  You'll have to add other styling and event triggers to get it to function correctly, but it's a start.